# how to reposition sidebar using grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a classic layout:

```
#divleft{
    float:left;
}

#sidebar{
    float:right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #divleft, #sidebar{
        float:none; 
}
```

`divleft` and `sidebar` are children of `panelb`;

Now I want to use grid

```
#panelb{
    width:calc(100% - 30px);
    margin:25px auto 0 auto;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 340px;
}
```

In this case how can I reposition `sidebar` below `divleft` on `900px` screen width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is just use media queries for the columns.

```css
#panelb {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin: 25px auto 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 340px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #panelb {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

#divleft {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

#sidebar {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='panelb'>
  <div id='divleft'></div>
  <div id='sidebar'></div>
</div>
```

And if you'd like to change the order, you can set the `order` property on #divleft and #sidebar.

I would also advise not to use id's but classes. Even for elements that only exist once because id's have some other weird properties like "leaking" to window and having a highered specificity in css.

Comment: thanks a lot. `class` instead of `id` - is it contrary to some basic rule? Have you any link to explain `leaking id`;

Comment: Every element with an ID can be found in your browser console using its name. So they all polute the global namespace. Can easily test that yourself.